# Reapply filter for GeoJSON in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

In Leaflet, I used a variable to insert a condition in a filter for a GeoJSON as follows:

```
var stareInt = "start";
var elements;

var geojsonStyle = {
 radius: 6,
 fillColor: "#6bad9f",
 color: "#FFF",
 className: 'point',
 pane: "pointPanel",
 weight: 1,
 opacity: 0.9,
 fillOpacity: 0.8
};


elements = L.geoJSON(elem_build, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return new L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonStyle, {
}).on('click', function() {
    this.bindPopup(feature.properties.grad_int).openPopup();
});
},

filter: function(feature, layer) {    
  if (stareInt == "01") {  
    return (feature.properties.grad_int == "very good");
  }
  else if (stareInt == "02") {
    return (feature.properties.grad_int == "good");
  }
  else {
    return feature.properties.grad_int == "bad";            
  }
 },

onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

The filters are actived by clicking buttons, like this:

```
$("#buttonA").click(function() {
 map.removeLayer(elements);
 stareInt= "01";
 map.addLayer(elements);
});
```

But I see that only the last state is returned (in this case, 'bad').

I guess that I have to reapply the filter or something similar, since Leaflet doesn't remember it.

How can I get the filter buttons to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `filter` callback function runs **once**, when your `L.GeoJson` is instantiated. Leaflet does **not** reapply the filter on a `L.GeoJson` when the layer is (re-)added to the map. This is by design. You can check this by looking at [the source code for `L.GeoJson`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/GeoJSON.js).

One approach is to have three different instances of `L.GeoJson`, each with a different filter applied:

```
var elements_verygood = L.geoJson(elem_build, {
    filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.grad_int == "very good"); }
});

var elements_good = L.geoJson(elem_build, {
    filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.grad_int == "good"); }
});

var elements_bad = L.geoJson(elem_build, {
    filter: function(feat) { return feat.properties.grad_int == "bad"); }
});
```

You can then toggle stuff with external buttons:

```
document.getElementById("buttonA").addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.removeLayer(elements_good);
    map.removeLayer(elements_bad);
    map.addLayer(elements_verygood);
});
```

But this is also a good scenario to use a `L.Control.Layers`:

```
L.control.layers({}, {
    "Very good": elements_verygood,
    "Good": elements_good,
    "Bad": elements_bad,
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Got it! I was afraid that creating several instances of `L.GeoJson` would lead to losing some functions that I had on `elements`, but it seems they work just fine. If I wanted to make three different filters instead of one, should I follow the same steps?

Comment: It might depend on the specifics of your data set and use case. If you *must* deal with multiple dynamic variables, maybe re-creating the `L.GeoJSON` instance each time would be best.